# DJango filter_queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am new to DJango and DRF and have been asked to manage some DJango/DRF related code. After a lot of search I am still unable to find a complete example on how filter_queryset works and how can it be used with different arguments.

At some places I see it used like the following,

```
self.filter_queryset(queryset)
```

and at other places it is used with some arguments. It would be helpful if some one can explain the fundamentals like how and when to use it, what are the dependent variables (lookup_field, filter_backends etc...) and arguments and how to set them up.

I have searched a lot and also gone through the docs. If i have missed any doc kindly let me know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [**`filter_queryset()`**--(source code)](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L142) is a method which is originally implemented in [**`GenericAPIView`** -- (DRF doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) class.

> ```
> def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
>     """
>     Given a queryset, filter it with whichever filter backend is in use.
>     You are unlikely to want to override this method, although you may need
>     to call it either from a list view, or from a custom `get_object`
>     method if you want to apply the configured filtering backend to the
>     default queryset.
>     """
>     for backend in list(self.filter_backends):
>         queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
>     return queryset
> ```

I think the functionality of the method is clearly visible from the doc strings.

---

> ".....and at other places it is used with some arguments"

The `views`'s **`filter_queryset()`** method takes only one parameter, which is the `queryset` to be filtered.
But, `filter-backends`' **`filter_queryset()`** method takes three arguments which are **`request`**,**`queryset`** and the **`view`** itself.

---

**What are FilterBackends?**
Filterbackends are classes which helps us to filter the queryset with complex lookups and some other stuff.
DRF has few built-in backends [which can be found here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/filters.py).DRF official docs recommend to use [**`django-filter`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/) package for advanced filtering purposes.

**How filter-backend working?**
Take a look at the source code of [**`DjangoFilterBackend`**](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/master/django_filters/rest_framework/backends.py#L20) class and it's methods...It's **`filter_queryset(...)`** method plays key role in the filtering process.

I would recommend to go through the doc of [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to understand the usage of the same with more examples.
By defining [**`filterset_class`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class), you could've more controll over the filtering process (such as providing `lookup_expr` etc)

Comment: Hi JPG, thanks for the answer and yes it did help. I saw some implementation where they use **kwargs. But now i suspect it might be a custom implementation. However, can you clarify how does the backend filter the query set? where are the keywords defined using which the queryset would be filtered by this method. Will all the keywords have to match or any one of them (and / or). Kindly direct me and let me tryout one small snippet and I shall accept your reply as the answer..And the built-in backend code was really helpful.

Comment: Hey JPG! I just managed to install the django-filter package and filtered the queryset successfully. Thanks for the reply I am marking it as an answer because it gave me the right direction.